# Go To Hierarchy Addition option in visual debugging (NetBeans) doesn't work

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

So, I am using the Anagram game sample in Apache NetBeans (12.5 SE) to test some debugging options.

I started the debugging session and took a snapshot of the GUI so I can make it easier to locate different code source that I need to verify. When I right-click a button in the snapshot and choose **Go To Component Declaration** or **Go To Component Source**, everything works fine. Only the **Go To Hierarchy Addition** seems to do Nothing.

Go To Hierarchy Addition is disabled by default in the IDE, I checked it in *Tools> Option> Java> Java Debugger> Visual Debugger*, and restarted the debugging session.

I hope I can identify what I've missed. Thank you!

[Here is a screenshot of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8LTg.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe you found a bug :) please report to https://netbeans.apache.org/participate/report-issue.html